# Перевод из инфиксной в постфиксную запись на Javascript по книге Лафоре

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм по книге Лафоре. Пока только для однозначных чисел.
Для выражения 5+4+1+2*3 получается требуемое 54+1+23*+, а вот 5+4+1+2*3-9 выдает
54+1+23*9-+ вместо 54+1+23*+9-. Что не так?

```
ops = {'+':1, '-':1, '/':2, '*':2};
    s = '1+2-3+4-5*6-7'.split('');
    stack = [];
    out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if(!isNaN(s[i])){
            out += s[i];
        }
        if(isNaN(s[i])){
            a = stack[stack.length - 1];
            if(stack.length == 0) {stack.push(s[i])}
            else {
                if(ops[a] >= ops[s[i]]) {
                    out += a;
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(s[i]);
                }
                if(ops[a] < ops[s[i]]) {
                    console.log('элемент ' +s[i] + ' > ' + ' кон. стека ' + a);
                    stack.push(s[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (i == s.length - 1) {
            out += stack.pop();
            console.log('конец строки',stack)
            out += stack.pop();
            console.log('конец строки',stack)
        }
        console.log(s[i],'out',out, 'stack', stack);
    }
    console.log('out is',out);
```

Comment: У тебя алгоритм в принципе плохо обрабатывает концы последовательностей. Например, "3+1" выводит фигню. А по теме вопроса - ты же добавил отладочный вывод, в чём проблема понять, на каком шаге ломается? Возьми выражение, распиши на бумажке, какое состояние переменных `out` и `stack` ты ожидаешь после каждой итерации и так найдёшь, на каком шаге сломалось.

Comment: Посмотри алгоритм в Википедии  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC Там написано "пока на вершине стека ... выталкиваем верхний элемент стека в выходную строку", т.е. д.б. цикл `while`, а ты один раз проверяешь `if(ops[a] >= ops[s[i]])` и уходишь на следующую итерацию.

Comment: Благодарю, с этим разобрался. 
https://jsfiddle.net/79xg8ykt/
Теперь осталось разобраться со скобками